# Добавление строк по пропущенным датам в столбце

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Есть датафрейм df

| Data | A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | A | 5 |
| 01.02.2020 | A | 7 |
| 01.04.2020 | A | 9 |
| 01.06.2020 | B | 1 |
| 01.09.2020 | B | 3 |

Как добавить строки с пропущенной датой. С заполнением поля A1 значением А или В, в зависимости где пропущено и А2 нулем? Реализовал через цикл, но это не эффективно. Как средствами пандас реализовать, не могу понять.

Желаемый результат:

| Data | A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | A | 5 |
| 01.02.2020 | A | 7 |
| 01.03.2020 | A | 0 |
| 01.04.2020 | A | 9 |
| 01.06.2020 | B | 1 |
| 01.07.2020 | B | 0 |
| 01.08.2020 | B | 0 |
| 01.09.2020 | B | 3 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужны каждые 1 числа месяца, между пропущенными датами:

```
res = (df
       .set_index("Data")
       .reindex(pd.date_range(df["Data"].min(), df["Data"].max(), freq="1MS")))
res["A1"] = res["A1"].ffill()
res["A2"] = res["A2"].fillna(0)

In [36]: res
Out[36]:
           A1   A2
2020-01-01  A  5.0
2020-02-01  A  7.0
2020-03-01  A  0.0
2020-04-01  A  9.0
2020-05-01  A  0.0
2020-06-01  B  1.0
2020-07-01  B  0.0
2020-08-01  B  0.0
2020-09-01  B  3.0
```

Comment: Спасибо! Прочитал документацию к date_range и пришел к этому же)

Answer (score 4):

```
res = df.set_index("Data").reindex(pd.date_range(df["Data"].min(), df["Data"].max()))

res["A1"] = res["A1"].ffill()

res["A2"] = res["A2"].fillna(0)
```

результат:

```
In [49]: res
Out[49]:
           A1   A2
2020-01-01  A  5.0
2020-01-02  A  7.0
2020-01-03  A  0.0
2020-01-04  A  9.0
2020-01-05  A  0.0
2020-01-06  B  1.0
2020-01-07  B  0.0
2020-01-08  B  0.0
2020-01-09  B  3.0
```

Comment: В целом получилось, только у меня дни пропущенные добавились, но не месяцы

Comment: @Twanger, можете привести [в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1240249/edit) __воспроизводимый__ пример данных?

Comment: IIn [137]: res.head(10)
Out[137]:
           A1   A2
2020-01-01  A  5.0

2020-01-02  A  0.0

2020-01-03  A  0.0

2020-01-04  A  0.0

2020-01-05  A  0.0

2020-01-06  A  0.0

2020-01-07  A  0.0

2020-01-08  A  0.0

2020-01-09  A  0.0

2020-01-10  A  0.0

Comment: @Twanger, что я должен увидеть в этом выводе??

Comment: Извиняюсь, так получилось. Вкратце, добавляет строки 1 января 2020, 2 января 2020 и т.д. Очень хочется, чтобы было 1 января, 1 февраля, 1 марта и т.д. Но спасибо за решение. Буду думать как допилить, до нужного результата)

Comment: Т.е. вам нужны даты - первые числа каждого месяца?

Comment: Да, вы правы, каждые 1 числа месяца, между пропущенными датами

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119358/discussion-between-twanger-and-maxu).