# Добавить пропущенные даты к каждой группе

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Есть датафрейм:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['b21', 'b21', 'c56', 'b21', 'c56', 'c56'],
              'status':['created', 'delivered', 'created', 'done', 'delivered', 'done'],
              'date':['2023-01-13', '2023-01-15', '2023-01-15', '2023-01-18', '2023-01-19', '2023-01-20']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

| id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b21 | created | 2023-01-13 |
| b21 | delivered | 2023-01-15 |
| c56 | created | 2023-01-15 |
| b21 | done | 2023-01-18 |
| c56 | delivered | 2023-01-19 |
| c56 | done | 2023-01-20 |

Необходимо добавить даты, которых нет в датафрейме и заполнить их предыдущими значениями. При этом заполнить так, чтобы для каждого id даты не выходили за рамки даты старта *(status = 'created')* и даты окончания *(status = 'done')*
В итоге должен получиться такой датафрейм:

| id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b21 | created | 2023-01-13 |
| b21 | created | 2023-01-14 |
| b21 | delivered | 2023-01-15 |
| c56 | created | 2023-01-15 |
| b21 | delivered | 2023-01-16 |
| c56 | created | 2023-01-16 |
| b21 | delivered | 2023-01-17 |
| c56 | created | 2023-01-17 |
| b21 | done | 2023-01-18 |
| c56 | created | 2023-01-18 |
| c56 | delivered | 2023-01-19 |
| c56 | done | 2023-01-20 |

[Похожий вопрос уже существует](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1240249/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B5), однако решение, которое там предлагают, не работает из - за пересечения дат в разных группах. Это приводит к ошибке `ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels`

P.S. Нашёл способ сделать это через цикл:

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df['id'].unique():
    new_df = df[df['id'] == i]
    d_range = pd.date_range(new_df['date'].min(), new_df['date'].max(), freq='D').to_frame(name='date')
    new_df = new_df.merge(d_range, how='right', on='date').fillna(method = 'ffill')
    result = pd.concat([result, new_df]).sort_values(['date', 'id'])
result
```

Однако реальный датасет будет довольно объёмным, поэтому хотелось бы найти способ увеличить производительность методами pandas

Comment: другие решения будут скорее всего мало чем отличаться принципиально, все равно будет либо явный цикл, либо имплицитный через группировку. но, возможно, дадут выигрыш по эффективности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать `groupby()`

```
result = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.merge(pd.date_range(x['date'].min(), x['date'].max(), freq='D').to_series(name='date'), how='right',
                      on='date').fillna(method='ffill')).sort_values('date')
```

```
    id     status       date
0  b21    created 2023-01-13
1  b21    created 2023-01-14
2  b21  delivered 2023-01-15
0  c56    created 2023-01-15
3  b21  delivered 2023-01-16
1  c56    created 2023-01-16
4  b21  delivered 2023-01-17
2  c56    created 2023-01-17
5  b21       done 2023-01-18
3  c56    created 2023-01-18
4  c56  delivered 2023-01-19
5  c56       done 2023-01-20
```

Comment: А не подскажете, возможно ли добавить условие внутри apply: если последний статус заказа != "done", то заполнять вплоть до сегодняшней даты `pd.date_range(x['date'].min(), pd.Timestamp.now(), freq='D')`, а если status = "done", то заполнять, как есть `pd.date_range(x['date'].min(), x['date'].max(), freq='D')`?  
Конечно, это снова можно сделать циклом, но мне кажется через groupby тоже реализуемо, только я не понимаю как.

Comment: Можно вместо лямбды написать функцию и в ней уже реализовать более сложный алгоритм. Будет .apply(fun)